# How to leave the 1st inline object when trying to delete all inline objects on "Change" page in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, admin

I have `Person` model and `Email` model which has the foreign key of `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And, I have `Person` admin which has `Email` inline as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

And, there are 3 inline objects on **Change** page as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to leave the 1st inline object when trying to delete all inline objects as shown below. *By default, all inline objects are deleted if trying to delete all inline objects:

[image]

So, how can I leave the 1st inline object when trying to delete all inline objects on **Change** page in Django Admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can override [save_existing_objects()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L917) and [delete_existing()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L771) by extending [forms.BaseInlineFormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), then set `EmailInlineFormSet` to `formset` in `EmailInline` as shown below to leave the 1st inline object when trying to delete all inline objects on **Change** page in Django Admin:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInlineFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    
    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
        self.counts = 0
        return super().save_existing_objects(commit)

    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        if  len(self.initial_forms) == len(self.deleted_forms):
            if self.counts < 1:
                self.counts += 1
                return
        
        if commit:
            obj.delete()

class EmailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Email
    formset = EmailInlineFormSet # Here

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (EmailInline,)
```

Then, if trying to delete all inline objects as shown below:

[image]

Then, you can leave the 1st inline object as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if trying to delete the 1st inline object as shown below:

[image]

Then, you cannot delete the 1st inline object as shown below:

[image]

In addition again, if changing `self.counts < 1` to `self.counts < 2` in `delete_existing()` as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class EmailInlineFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    # ...

    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        if self.deleted_obj_counts == self.obj_counts:
            if self.counts < 2: # Here
                self.counts += 1
                return
        
        if commit:
            obj.delete()

# ...
```

Then, if trying to delete all inline objects as shown below:

[image]

Then, you can leave the 1st and 2nd inline objects as shown below:

[image]